# Makefile pep8 checks only the git diff

Tags: git, makefile, pep8

we use a `pep8` target in our repo's Makefile to check for PEP8 compliance on all python files:

```
## Check all python files for compatibility with PEP8
PEP8FLAGS := --ignore=E201,E202,E241,E265,E501,E711,E712,E713,E714,E721,W391,W291,W293,W601,W603
pep8:
    pep8 $(PEP8FLAGS) .
```

I'd like to have a similar `pep8-changes` target that only checks against the Python files changed in pull requests:

```
DIFF_FILES := (git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR ; \  # ACMR: added/copied/modified/renamed
           git diff --staged --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR ; \
           git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR upstream/master...) \
| sort | uniq | grep -e "\.py$$" | grep -v '__init__.py'

## Check all diff python files for compatibility with PEP8
pep8-changes:
    pep8 $(PEP8FLAGS) --filename $(DIFF_FILES)
```

But I get the following error:

```
pep8 --exclude=sandbox,thirdparty --ignore=E201,E202,E241,E265,E501,E711,E712,E713,E714,E721,W391,W291,W293,W601,W603 --filename (git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR ; \
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I'm not finding much help in the [pep8 docs](http://pep8.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.7.x/intro.html#example-usage-and-output); I don't think the `--diff` flag is what I'm looking for here. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You don't mention which particular `make` variant you are using, but if it is GNU make or compatible, you either want `var != command` or `var := $(shell command)`. There are several other potential issues in your setup as well, depending on precisely what you're trying to accomplish here. In particular if you want to do this before actually making a commit, beware of the difference between what's in the *index* and what's in the *work-tree*.

Comment: @torek it would be GNU make. And to be more specific, `make pep8-changes` is a command run by Jenkins on every push, so the difference is between the pushed branch and upstream/master.

Comment: OK - in that case, there's no point in either `git diff` (index vs work-tree) or `git diff --staged` (`HEAD` vs index). Ditching those two means there's no need for `uniq` either, which simplifies everything quite a bit. It's probably wise to avoid `C` and `R` file states (which produce two file names, not just one) by using `git diff-tree -r`, although that precludes the handy three-dot `...` syntax for finding merge bases—but it also seems unlikely that you *want* to find a merge base here.

Comment: Okay thank you, this simplifies things a bit. But I still have the issue that the `DIFF_FILES` doesn't evaluate as expected for the `pep8` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it. Issues seemed to be around escaping the `$` char. Here's the final:

```
DIFF_FILES := git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMR upstream/master... \
| sort | uniq | grep -e "\.py$$" | grep -v '__init__.py'

pep8-changes:
    pep8 $(PEP8FLAGS) `$(DIFF_FILES)`
```

Comment: You still don't need the `| sort | uniq`, and using the triple-dot syntax still seems wrong (you don't intend to diff the *merge base* of `upstream/master` and `HEAD` against `HEAD`, you intend to diff `upstream/master` against HEAD). You can also get the `*.py` matching directly from Git (using pathspecs), though excluding `__init__.py` is probably still easiest with `grep -v`.